# How and where can we run a code which depends on the sender's address

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

The add-in I'm trying to build has to change the BCC field of a new mail depending on the sender's address.

As I'm new to Outlook programming, I foud this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) and built the example add-in.
The event they used is [NewInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorsevents_event.newinspector.aspx), which, as you can read, is fired right before a new outlook item window appears. However if we paste this code in the NewInspector event handler:

```
        Outlook.MailItem item = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.EntryID == null)
            {
                if (item.SenderEmailAddress == "...")
                    item.BCC = "....";
            }
        }
```

It **doesn't** work, because the sender's address is empty when the window has just loaded.

I thought about using the [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.send) event, each new mail created will have its Send event handler attached to a method which, in its turn, will change the BCC depending on the sender's address when the email is sent.

The only problem is, for some reason, I can't see the Send event in VS 2010 Pro.

Are there any other ways to do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **event interface** ([Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event_members.aspx)) of the [`Outlook.MailItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem) since it has both a [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.send.aspx) and [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.send.aspx) tied to the same name (*`Send`*). This is just one of the quirks you have to be aware of in the Outlook Object Model. This should work for you:

```
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)MailItem).Send += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(MailItem_Send);
```